# htaccess выше точки входа

Tags: .htaccess, чпу

Собственно вопрос. Возможно ли?

При переносе за пределы корня сайта (в данном случае папка public_html) отваливаются стили, скрипты и главная. Но страницы в принципе отрабатывают, т.е. ЧПУ продолжает работать.

Если такое возможно, то в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

htaccess - это тот же конфиг апача с настройкой хоста, только который действует на одну папку.
В нем обычно расписывают правила для обработки запросов (например, если все запросы нужно направить на index.php). Коли у тебя отвалились статические файлы, то очевидно, что апач их просто найти не может. Может ты их спрашиваешь по старой урл-ке?

Вот простым языком:
https://beget.ru/articles/htaccess

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. На насколько я понимаю апач берёт настройки из конфига в /etc/apache2/sites-available/ + добавляются локальные собранные по папкам начиная от точки входа указанного в DocumentRoot. Собственно вопрос. Можно ли перенести htaccess уровнем выше папки указанной в DocumentRoot?

Comment: Вроде того. Первое, что лезет в голову - попробуй использовать линуксовый symlink на htaccess в нужном месте, ну а вообще, ты можешь перенсти все из этого htaccess'а (который хочешь выше документрута положить) в настройку хоста (/etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.conf )

Comment: Думал об этом. Переносить в настройку хоста пробовал. Отрабатывает нормально. Если случай единичный то можно, но если на постоянку с каждым сайтом дополнительные пляски с бубном не очень вдохновляют. Пусть будет на месте.